# Cómo actualizar el proyecto en visual studio después de borrar un botón

Tags: c#, devexpress, visual-studio-2010

Buenas tengo este problema, coloque un botón en un formulario de mi proyecto, y este tenia un evento con código implementado, pero después decidí borrar el botón y también el método. ahora al momento de compilar el proyecto me sale este error:

> Error  4   'CapaPresentacion.z' no contiene una definición de 'barButtonItem1_ItemClick_1' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'barButtonItem1_ItemClick_1' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'CapaPresentacion.z' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?)**

al parecer aun sigue buscando el componente,como puedo hacer para actualizar el proyecto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: porque el titulo en mayusculas ?

Comment: eliminaste el código de una función que llama el botón, antes de eliminarlo, supongo.

Comment: Puedes determinar donde se genera este problema? es quizas en el Designer.cs de form. Si realizar un Rebuild de la solicion quizas fuerces la actualizacion del codigo

Comment: Como comenta Leandro tienes que fijarte en el archivo Designer.cs, ya que aunque elimines el botón y el metodo a veces Visual Studio no borra la referencia del archivo, ahi deberás ver una referencia a barButtonItem1_ItemClick_1 += metodoEliminado(e,sender); elimina esa linea y vuelve a compilar tu solución

Comment: ya lo solucione, al parecer aun se encontraba declarado en el proyecto ,aun contenía ese componente aparecía en la pestaña esquema del documento así que solo lo elimine. Y listo compilo. Gracias por su apoyo.